# Plotting Chebyshev's theta function $\vartheta(x)$

Tags: plotting, number-theory

The function I would like to plot is defined as $\sum\limits_{p\leq x}\log p.$ The following gives me I think a plot of the points of interest, but the function is defined for all $x > 0$ and so it's basically a step function between primes. Is there a way to augment the following to include the "steps?"

```
a8 = Table[Sum[Log[Prime[i]], {i, 1, j}], {j, 1, 10}];

a7 = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 10}];

a9 = Table[{a7[[i]], a8[[i]]}, {i, 1, 10}];

ListPlot[a9]
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's Eric Weisstein's implementation from MathWorld:

```
Primorial[0] := 1;
Primorial[1] := 2;
Primorial[n_] := Primorial[n] = Prime[n] Primorial[n - 1];
ChebyshevTheta[n_] := Log[Primorial[PrimePi[n]]]

Plot[ChebyshevTheta[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Many MathWorld pages have attached notebooks linked near the top of the page.  That's where this came from.

Comment: Thank you I had seen this but did not realize there was code to be found.

Comment: @daniel Yes, the code is the best part of the answer!

Comment: You might need some more `PlotPoints` in there to get rid of that wee glitch in the middle.

Comment: It might be more prudent to just add logarithms directly instead of multiplying a bunch of primes before taking the logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to stay as close to your definitions as possible, one may actually want to avoid `Plot` because it will have trouble when the number of discontinuities is too large to be properly resolved for a given choice of `PlotPoints`. Instead, as you already started out doing, one can use a list plot. But to get lines, you should use `ListLinePlot` and define the corners of the step functions:

```
n = 50;

a8 = Table[Sum[Log[Prime[i]], {i, 1, j}], {j, 1, n}];

a7 = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 50}];

a9 = Transpose[{a7, a8}];

a10 = Transpose[{Rest[a7], Most[a8]}];

ListLinePlot[Riffle[a9, a10]]
```

[image: steps]

This guarantees all steps to be nicely rectangular. Here, the number of jumps is given by `n = 50`.

What I did is to simplify your definition of `a9` without changing it, and then adding a list `a10` where all the `x`-values are shifted to the right in order to define the right side of each horizontal segment. These two lists `a9` and `a10` are then combined with `Riffle` so that elements from each list alternate, giving the desired line.

You can increase `n` without having to worry about the `PlotPoints` option in `Plot`.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen "Riffle" before. This is a nice idea and I did notice for large n a lot of error messages before the Weisstein implementation actually displayed the graph. +1